# Poor video call reliability despite high speeds

Tags: networking

I am struggling a little with my home network - video calls when connected to a 2nd router are often pixelated or freeze, despite download speeds of around 20-30MB. I should also clarify that these calls happen outside, but we are within 7 meters of the router, and there is only glass in between the router and computer.

Googling shows speed is unlikely the cause of the problem, more about the stability. When I add a continuous ping, I see it often drops at the same time we struggle on a video call. Seems like I have found a potential cause.

I have a bog standard PlusNet (ISP) router and it works fine for all devices in the vicinity (wired and wireless). As the strength wasn't good enough on the other side of the house (where I am having the video call issues), I have hard wired an ethernet cable from Ethernet Port 1 on my PlustNet router, 20 metres to my TP Link router. This means we now have wireless internet from any where.

My set up (including how I set it up):

Plusnet Router: DHCP enabled. IP Range: 192.168.1.2 > 19.168.1.200. The default gateway is 192.168.1.254 (hopefully this is OK as it's outside the IP range)

AP-Router (TP Link): DHCP disabled. IP of router: 192.168.1.201. Different Wireless SSID/password etc

There is a physical ethernet cable connecting the 2 routers.

Is there anything special I can do to stabalise the connection? Is dropped packages like this potentially a sign of poor hardware?

Comment: I fully appreciate this issue may not be replicable and may be too broad. Apologies in advance if this wastes any-ones time

Comment: It is a difficult question to troubleshoot in general.   It may be that you can mitigate the issue by using QoS (Quality of Service) and traffic shaping/prioritising on your network - of-course this wont do much if your ISP is where the blockage is.     Also, WIFI is not particularly reliable/consistent - if you are connecting via Wireless, that is a very likely source of problems and bottlenecks - sometimes better hardware will help with this, but using a physical cable is better if its an option.

Comment: How did you connect the TP-Link to the network (which ethernet port did you use, what IP and DHCP configuration did you do if any)? How do you know when you're connecting via TP-Link's wi-fi vs PlusNet's? Does the TP-Link offer 5GHz or only 2.4GHz?

Comment: @user1686, yeah, those are great questions and relates to my point about the 2nd router (TP Link) not showing as a connected device. Because it is not connected, I do not know the IP address. I can not remember how I set up that router :(

Comment: Bandwidth and all is great, but what about latency and packet loss? Your video call tool may have some statistics for that.

Comment: It is Skype - I will Google for information